# Como puedo estructurar bien mi AuthGuard para no generar bucle infinito

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs, auth, guards

Soy nuevo en Angular y estoy tratando de crear un AuthGuard para proteger mis rutas por lo que hago este codigo pero me crea un bucle infinito y nunca puedo entrar a la pantalla.

Este es el codigo de mi AuthGuard:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivateFn, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) => {
  const _ROUTER: Router = inject(Router);
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('TA');

  if (isAuthenticated !== null) {
    console.log('true')
    return _ROUTER.navigate(['dashboard']);
  } else {
    console.log('false')
    return _ROUTER.navigate(['login']);
  }
};
```

**Espero me puedan ayudar**

Answer (score 0):

se te esta generando un bucle ya que todos los return del guard estan retornando una url, lo que significa que al validar dentro de tu guard, vuelve a cargar la url, por lo tanto debe cargar nuevamente el guard y asi eternamente...

el guard deberia tener un **return true**, lo que significa que la validacion del guard fue exitosa, entonces el componente puede ser cargado, de lo contrario hacer return tal como los que haz realizado, a una pagina 404 por ejemplo, que no tenga guard

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene un problema de bucle infinito porque usas el método **navigate** del **router** dentro del guardia **canActivate**, lo que provocaba que se volviera a evaluar la expresión de la vista y se llamara de nuevo a la función **getValueAsync**. Esto hace que se realice una petición HTTP con el servicio $http, que a su vez disparaba el ciclo **$digest** de Angular y reiniciaba el proceso.

No deberías usar inject para obtener una instancia de Router, ya que esto puede causar errores en la inyección de dependencias. En su lugar, deberías inyectar Router en el constructor de tu clase AuthGuard y asignarlo a una propiedad privada. Esto te permitirá acceder al router en tu método canActivate.

No deberías usar localStorage para almacenar el estado de autenticación, ya que esto puede ser inseguro y vulnerable a ataques. En su lugar, deberías usar un servicio de autenticación que implemente un mecanismo más robusto, como tokens JWT o cookies seguras.

No deberías usar console.log para depurar tu código, ya que esto puede afectar al rendimiento y la seguridad de tu aplicación. En su lugar, deberías usar herramientas de depuración integradas en tu navegador o IDE, o usar un servicio de registro como Sentry o LogRocket.

No deberías usar return para navegar a otras rutas, ya que esto puede interrumpir el ciclo de vida de tu guardia. En su lugar, deberías usar return true o return false para indicar si la ruta puede ser activada o no, y usar el método navigateByUrl del router para redirigir al usuario.

Aquí tienes una versión corregida de tu código:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    const isAuthenticated = this.authService.isAuthenticated();

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
      return false;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```